# How use setID in android correctly?

Tags: android

I want to add layout with controls dynamically and in the future I want to save this data to DB.

```
public void onClickAdd(View view) {
    LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final LinearLayout subLayoutFields = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.subLayoutFields);
    LinearLayout subLayoutFields1;
    final View view1 = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_fields, subLayoutFields, true);
    subLayoutFields.setId(countID);
    countID++;
}
```

And compiler did not finish successful.What's wrong with this?I get error on the

```
subLayoutFields.setId(countID);
```

The error is a:

> Reports two types of problems: Supplying the wrong type of resource
>   identifier. For example, when calling Resources.getString(int id), you
>   should be passing R.string.something, not R.drawable.something.
>   Passing the wrong constant to a method which expects one of a specific
>   set of constants. For example, when calling View#setLayoutDirection,
>   the parameter must be android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR or
>   android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL

Thank you...

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: Reports two types of problems:
Supplying the wrong type of resource identifier. For example, when calling Resources.getString(int id), you should be passing R.string.something, not R.drawable.something.
Passing the wrong constant to a method which expects one of a specific set of constants. For example, when calling View#setLayoutDirection, the parameter must be android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR or android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL.

Comment: Not here, edit it into the question

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve. You are inflating some views, and then doing nothing with them, seems a waste of CPU as you posted it. Also why would you like to change the id? I have posted below a code hot to setId, but that is usually use when you are dynamically adding views programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
someView.setId(GenerateViewId.generateId());
```

This is the UTIL you need

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class GenerateViewId {

    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

    /**
     * Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int}.
     * This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.
     *
     * @return a generated ID value
     */
    private static int generateViewId() {
        for (; ; ) {
            final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) {
                newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            }
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int generateId() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return generateViewId();
        }
        else {
            return View.generateViewId();
        }
    }

}
```